# OpenBSD 6.7 how to install xbase

Tags: openbsd

I am updating our integration test environments to OpenBSD 6.7 (from 6.5)

We use ansible to install all the packages on the target system (openbsd 6.7, Vagrant image https://app.vagrantup.com/generic/boxes/openbsd6/versions/3.0.6 )

With the above image, I cannot install java openjdk 11.

```
obsd-31# pkg_add -r jdk%11     
quirks-3.325 signed on 2020-05-27T12:56:02Z
jdk-11.0.7.10.2p0v0:lz4-1.9.2p0: ok
jdk-11.0.7.10.2p0v0:zstd-1.4.4p1: ok
jdk-11.0.7.10.2p0v0:jpeg-2.0.4p0v0: ok
jdk-11.0.7.10.2p0v0:tiff-4.1.0: ok
jdk-11.0.7.10.2p0v0:lcms2-2.9p0: ok
jdk-11.0.7.10.2p0v0:png-1.6.37: ok
jdk-11.0.7.10.2p0v0:giflib-5.1.6: ok
Can't install jdk-11.0.7.10.2p0v0 because of libraries
|library X11.17.0 not found
| not found anywhere
|library Xext.13.0 not found
| not found anywhere
|library Xi.12.1 not found
| not found anywhere
|library Xrender.6.0 not found
| not found anywhere
|library Xtst.11.0 not found
| not found anywhere
|library freetype.30.0 not found
| not found anywhere
Direct dependencies for jdk-11.0.7.10.2p0v0 resolve to png-1.6.37 libiconv-1.16p0 giflib-5.1.6 lcms2-2.9p0 jpeg-2.0.4p0v0
Full dependency tree is giflib-5.1.6 lz4-1.9.2p0 tiff-4.1.0 png-1.6.37 xz-5.2.5 jpeg-2.0.4p0v0 lcms2-2.9p0 zstd-1.4.4p1 libiconv-1.16p0
Couldn't install jdk-11.0.7.10.2p0v0
```

my guess is that xbase is not installed.
However, I cannot figure out how to install xbase without rebooting into a bootable installer (because I need to do it via a shell command running from ansible)

Is there a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic OpenBSD Vagrant image you're using was created as a command line environment, so the X windows files were were excluded during the install process.
There are lots of ways to add X windows to OpenBSD after installation, but the quickest method that comes to mind would be:

```sh
sudo su -l
curl -LO 'https://ftp.usa.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/6.7/amd64/x{base,serv,font,share}67.tgz'
tar xzf xbase67.tgz -C / 
tar xzf xserv67.tgz -C / 
tar xzf xfont67.tgz -C / 
tar xzf xshare67.tgz -C / 
rm -f xbase67.tgz xfont67.tgz xserv67.tgz xshare67.tgz
ldconfig /usr/local/lib /usr/X11R6/lib
```

If you would like to test for the presence of X windows on OpenBSD, try using the following shell snippet:

```sh
if [ -d /usr/X11R6/bin/ ] && [ -f /usr/X11R6/bin/xinit ]; then
  echo "X windows has been installed."
else
  echo "This is a command line only system."
fi
```

Comment: thank you. For our needs command line env fits well. The initial problem was, however,  that OpenBSD does not seem to have a headless JDK package, so the only one that exists is not headless. And that prevents a JDK installation on a OpenBSD without xbase

Answer (score 3):

The xbase [file set](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq4.html#FilesNeeded) can be extracted manually via the following commands:

```sh
cd /
curl -LO https://ftp.usa.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/6.7/amd64/xbase67.tgz
tar xzvf xbase67.tgz
```

Note: this is the mirror used in the [vagrant sources](https://github.com/lavabit/robox/blob/master/scripts/openbsd6/pkg.sh#L4).

Comment: this worked. thank you. and I was able to install java 11 with the above noted command. I do not have, yet, have a way to detect from ansible if xbase is actually installed or not (to trigger execution of the above download) -- but that's an independent question that can be implement with ansible shell module

Answer (score 0):

If you care about security enough to use OpenBSD, then you really shouldn't grab new package sets from the internet without also checking the hashes/signatures are valid. Try this script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo -n "Downloading ... "
curl --silent --fail --fail-early -O "https://ftp.usa.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/7.0/amd64/SHA256.sig" -O "https://ftp.usa.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/7.0/amd64/x{base,font,serv,share}70.tgz"
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
  echo "X windows download failed. Terminating."
  exit 1
fi
echo "complete."

signify -Cp /etc/signify/openbsd-70-base.pub -x SHA256.sig xbase70.tgz xfont70.tgz xserv70.tgz xshare70.tgz
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
  echo "X windows signature verification failed. Terminating."
  exit 1
fi

tar -z -x -C / -f xbase70.tgz && tar -z -x -C / -f xfont70.tgz && tar -z -x -C / -f xserv70.tgz && tar -z -x -C / -f xshare70.tgz
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
  echo "X windows installation failed. Terminating."
  exit 1
fi
echo "Installation complete. Happy hacking."
```

On the other hand if you just want a one liners:

```
# Install just x11 base set.
sudo ksh -c 'curl --silent https://ftp.usa.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/7.0/amd64/xbase70.tgz | gzip -d -c | tar -x -C / -f - '

# Install all the x11 sets.
sudo ksh -c 'curl --silent https://ftp.usa.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/7.0/amd64/xbase70.tgz | gzip -d -c | tar -x -C /-f - '
```

You can omit the `sudo` portion if you are already logged in as root. And for the `vagrant` folks, the lazy version looks:

```
# Install just x11 base set from the host, to a vagrant guest.
vagrant ssh -c "sudo ksh -c 'curl --silent https://ftp.usa.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/7.0/amd64/xbase70.tgz | gzip -d -c | tar -x -C / -f - '"

# Install all the x11 sets from the host, to a vagrant guest.
vagrant ssh -c "sudo ksh -c 'curl --silent -O \"https://ftp.usa.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/7.0/amd64/x{base,font,serv,share}70.tgz\" && tar -z -x -C / -f xbase70.tgz && tar -z -x -C / -f xfont70.tgz && tar -z -x -C / -f xserv70.tgz && tar -z -x -C / -f xshare70.tgz'"
```